# How to multithread file processing in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, file-processing

I'm working on one problem where I need to process 24 files (each size = 3 GB) and write the output into multiple files (24). Each file takes around 1 hour to process. Is it possible to write data into multiple files concurrently using multi-threading with below code?

```
 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        std::string path;
        cout << "Enter the folder of the logs:  " << endl; 
        cin >> path;

        WIN32_FIND_DATA FileInformation;       // File information  
        memset(&FileInformation, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));         
        std::string strExt =  "\\*.txt";
        std::string strEscape = "\\";
        std::string strPattern = path + strExt;             
        HANDLE hFile = ::FindFirstFile(strPattern.c_str(), &FileInformation);  

        while(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)     
        {
            int offset;
            std::ifstream Myfile;
            std::string strFileName = FileInformation.cFileName;
            std:: string fullPath = path + strEscape + strFileName;
            std::string outputFile = path + strEscape + strFileName.substr(0, strFileName.length()-3) + "processed"+".txt";
            std::ofstream ofs(outputFile, std::ofstream::out);

            Myfile.open (fullPath);
            std::string line;

            if(Myfile.is_open())
            {
                while(!Myfile.eof())
                {
                -------Processing--------
                }

                Myfile.close();

            }
            else
                cout<<"Cannot open file."<<endl;

            if(FindNextFile(hFile, &FileInformation) == FALSE)
                break;
        }      
        // Close handle  
        ::FindClose(hFile);        
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: If you're IO bound, multithreading wont help much. Have you looked into memory mapped files and the like ? (and `while(!Myfile.eof()) is almost aways wrong)

Comment: And on an HDD you'll get thrashing if you try to write too many files simultaneously. Still on a multi-core CPU (or with hyperthreading) you'll probably find you can support a certain number of threads at once without diminishing returns.

Comment: The answer to your question is "No, the code you show will not write data into multiple files using multi-threading."   On the other hand the answer to "is it possible to write data into multiple files using multithreading"  is "Yes".   If your real question is: Please write the code for me, then that is not a good question for this site.

Comment: @quantdev what he said + are you sure IO is your bottle neck? If it takes you 1 hour to process 3GB file I highly dough it's IO problem. I usually parse 7GB file in a minute or two.. so IO is maybe ~5% of your time.

Comment: @Vladp Then you multithread the processing, not the actual file writing (and I used a `if` :) )

Comment: @quantdev I meant that I support what you said + add more. multithreading the processing is a different matter which the OP doesn't interested in.

Comment: You will need multiple hard drive and/or SSD type hard drives in order to keep multiple files in "streaming" mode during read or write operations.

Comment: If you are on Windows 8 you can check available resources on your system using the Task Manager. If your disk utilization is at 100%, multithreading/-processing will not buy you anything. If, however, you are only using up 1 CPU core, chances are that multithreading/-processing will make sense (assuming a multi-core machine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into your code I assume you produce one output file from one input. In such case you do not need to write multithreaded code to check if processing multiple files at once will speed up the process. Just modify your program to accept file name as a parameter and run multiple of them in parallel. But unless you are reading/writing from/to SSD drive such parallel processing most probably would slow process down, as hard-drive will have to switch between reading/writing for multiple positions, and head positioning is slow.

It is not clear what you are doing on processing, but if it takes 100% CPU then you most probably will speed up process significantly by processing one file by multiple threads. You would have one thread reading, then thread pool processing, then one thread writing. Tricky part would be to synchronize data and make it not appear in output file in wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write multithreaded code here, write multiprocess code. That is, have your program process one file (which is passed as an argument), and call it multiple times in parallel from a script.

Don't run your program 24 times concurrently (unless you have 24 cores and 72GB of memory available). Try running 2, 4 or 6 instances concurrently and see what's best. I guess it'll be the number of cores, maybe the number of cores * 2 - 1 (hyperthreading does help). Try it out.

Also, if your program reads the file at the start, then performs the calculations, then writes the result, measure the time it takes to read the 3GB of data. If it's, for example, 30 seconds, and you run 4 processes concurrently, have your run script start the first instance, then wait 45 seconds, then start the second one and so on until the fourth. Start the fifth instance once one of the first four is finished. Every time another instance finishes, run the next one until all 24 have been run.